# Как грамотно составить Roadmap

Tags: python, panda3d, opensource, c++

Есть у меня [идея](http://ogre3d.su/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=548), на мой взгляд, [хорошая](http://habrahabr.ru/post/98740/). Но, как справедливо заметил товарищ Сиверс, идеи ничего не стоят без реализации. Идея довольно сложная с точки зрения программирования, и я пока ещё ничего сложнее 500 строк кода не писал, но всё случается в первый раз.

На данном этапе я занимаюсь (громко сказано) разработкой архитектуры (ещё громче сказано) программы: разбиваю основную задачу на подзадачи и составляю график выполнения работ. Вот тут-то и начинаются проблемы. Если с разбиением я худо-бедно справляюсь (на бумаге составил граф, что с чем связано), то вот с графиком у меня проблемы: хочется взяться за всё и сразу, а так нельзя. Нужен совет более опытного мастера.

Ну и вообще *любая* помощь приветствуется.

**Ещё два месяца спустя**

Желание реализовать эту задумку не утихает, скорее даже наоборот: зреет и крепнет. За это время со мной много чего случилось и не всегда было время на то, чтобы исследовать **панду** и заниматься проектом. Но я всё-таки успел пройти туториал на [MyGameFast](http://www.mygamefast.com/) (к сожалению, незавершённое автором), наговнокодить **[змейку](https://github.com/canadien91/cobra)**, которая вполне себе играбельная. Правда, в ней нет ни меню, ни возможности изменить скорость, ни таблицы результатов, в неё можно просто играть. Сейчас думаю над тем, стоит ли приводить её в более опрятный (с точки зрения кода и особенностей панды) вид или бросить её как есть и начать вплотную работать уже с **Mad Lab**.

Худо-бедно список фич, которые должны быть в версии 0.1 я набросал, но прежде всего нужно грамотно определить общую архитектуру программы с учётом особенностей панды, чтобы потом всё заново переписывать не пришлось.

**UPD OCT**

[Отчёт за сентябрь](http://montreal-reports.blogspot.com/2014/09/2014.html)

[Отчёт за октябрь](http://montreal-reports.blogspot.com/2014/10/2014.html)

Долго думал выкладывать тут эти ссылки или нет. Если прочитаете, то поймёте почему. Даже не знаю, буду ли выкладывать тут отчёт за ноябрь. В этом вопросе, пожалуй, лучше уже ничего не писать, если вдруг захотите со мной связаться, то пишите в джаббер: montreal@jabber.ru или на почту, указанную в профиле. Лучше будет сразу указать причину, по которой пишете.

**UPD NOV**

[Отчёт за ноябрь](http://canadien91.github.io/). Точнее, ноябрьский отчёт за октябрь. Написан, разумеется, в большей степени для себя и там вы найдёте все мои мысли о прошедшем месяце.

**PS** Не знаю, насколько всё это соответствует правилам хэшкода. Если мой вопрос сильно им противоречит, то я его переработаю.

**PPS** Если эта идея всё ещё кому-то интересна, то я могу завести бложик на blogspot'e, где можно писать "новости" 1-2 раза в месяц.

Comment: @Montreal, очень складно пишете (это про первую ссылку), только почему Пекин с *маленькой* буквы?

По поводу *любой помощи*.

Характеристики огнестрельного оружия видимо весьма условны? Не рассчитываете же Вы в самом деле победить мечем автоматчика?

Comment: @avp я всё это писал несколько часов, наверное, просто уже концентрации внимания не хватило.

Ну да, сказано же, что это как бы разработка для фанатов. С другой стороны, наличие у мечника брони, которая автоматом не пробивается даёт ему весьма весомое преимущество.

А за похвалу спасибо -- я старался.

Comment: @Montreal, правда увлекательно написано. Прочитал с удовольствием.

А не думаете, что в такой броне мечник просто не сможет сблизиться с противником (кроме обездвиженного или круглого идиота, причем независимо от его вооружения) и нанести эффективный удар?

Не знаю, как у фанатов, а мне нравится когда игрушка не слишком расходится с реальностью. Правда, давно уже в подобные штуки не играл.

Comment: @avp думаю, уже с современным уровнем технологий вполне реально такую броню сделать из какого-нибудь графена или силицена, не обязательно её даже экзоскелетом снабжать. Подбегает такой воен к стрелку и выбивает у него из рук оружие, после чего тот становится бессилен. Есть пример из истории Японии, когда в гражданской войне 1877 года самураи на мечах сражались против вооружённых винтовками императорских войск.

В общем, это вопрос баланса. Если оружие ближнего боя вдруг покажет свою несостоятельность, то его либо упразднить можно, либо понизить характеристики винтовок понизить.

Comment: @Montreal, возможно почти все. Только не стоит забывать, что в во все времена при поединке "атака" против "защиты" почти всегда преимущество было за "атакой".

Рассматривая технологию улучшения брони не стоит забывать о прогрессе в технологии боеприпасов.

Comment: @avp, наличие или отсутствие в игре мечей не принципиально. Я руководствовался тем, что чем больше способов прохождения игры, тем она интереснее. 

Лучше скажите, что вы думаете по поводу написания игровой логики на питоне?

Comment: Если учесть, что питоном толком я не владею (а только постоянно собираюсь его начать изучать, поскольку очень похоже что админская часть в \*nix-ах переползает с шелла на него (ха, змея меняет кожу (оболчку))),

то я к этому отношусь положительно, пока по памяти (насколько я заметил очень уж питон память любит жрать) проходит.

--

Вообще, для разработки прототипа очень многие в сети советуют именно питон.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще, после составления 5-6 графов, которые изображали бы архитектуру программы, у меня получилась вот такая штука. 
[image: Архитектура]

И, честно говоря, она мне не очень нравится. Вот почему: все остальные модули зависят от ядра и если вдруг придётся его изменить, то изменения могут затронуть всю программу, а это явный признак плохой архитектуры.

И потом: данный рисунок не отражает степень связанности разных модулей с ядром. Пожалуй, наиболее сильно с ядром связаны модули Input, GUI, Save/Load и AI. Чуть слабее связан 3D Render, так как он просто отрисовывает картинку, ну а генератор карт вообще почти никак с ядром не связан, от него требуется только генерировать карту по сигналу.

Возвращаясь к вопросу о том, как грамотно составить Roadmap, теперь я понимаю, что нужно начать с ядра, как бы это не было банально. После чего перейти к модулям ввода и рендера. Дальше GUI, Save/Load, генератор карт и AI.

Пока как-то так.

**Два месяца спустя**

За прошедшие два месяца в моей жизни поменялось довольно много: я переехал в другой город и нашёл работу. Мысли о **Mad Lab** не покидали мою голову и тут, ВНЕЗАПНО, случился невероятный прорыв: в сети я наткнулся на замечательный игровой движок, именуемый [Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org). Написан он на С++, но все функции можно вызывать из питона. Открыт для любого использования и включает в себя очень обширный набор инструментов, таких как работа с GUI, физикой и звуком!

Знакомиться с движком я только начал, но уже написал по инструкции своеобразный helloworld, в котором по небольшой сценке туда-сюда бродит панда, а камера вращается вокруг центра сцены. Всё это счастье укладывается в 45 строк кода на питоне, что не может не радовать. В голове уже начинает складываться пресловутый roadmap: "так сейчас нам нужно реализовать перемещение человечка по карте при помощи point-and-click, затем добавить врагов,NPC, шмот и всё заверте..."

А вот, собственно, и код:

```
from math import pi, sin, cos

from panda3d.core import Point3

from direct.task import Task
from direct.actor.Actor import Actor
from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
from direct.interval.IntervalGlobal import Sequence

class MyApp( ShowBase ):
    def __init__( self ):
        ShowBase.__init__( self )

        self.disableMouse( )

        self.environ      = self.loader.loadModel( "models/environment" )
        self.environ.reparentTo( self.render )
        self.environ.setScale( 0.25, 0.25, 0.25 )
        self.environ.setPos( -8, 42, 0 )

        self.taskMgr.add( self.spinCameraTask, "SpinCameraTask" )

        self.pandaActor   = Actor( "models/panda-model", { "walk": "models/panda-walk4" } )
        self.pandaActor.setScale( 0.005, 0.005, 0.005 )
        self.pandaActor.reparentTo( self.render )
        self.pandaActor.loop( "walk" )

        pandaPosInterval1 = self.pandaActor.posInterval( 13, Point3( 0, -10, 0 ), startPos=Point3( 0, 10, 0 ) )
        pandaPosInterval2 = self.pandaActor.posInterval( 13, Point3( 0, 10, 0 ), startPos=Point3( 0, -10, 0 ) )

        pandaHprInterval1 = self.pandaActor.hprInterval( 3, Point3( 180, 0, 0 ), startHpr=Point3( 0, 0, 0) )
        pandaHprInterval2 = self.pandaActor.hprInterval( 3, Point3( 0, 0, 0 ), startHpr=Point3( 180, 0, 0 ) )

        self.pandaPace    = Sequence( pandaPosInterval1, pandaHprInterval1, pandaPosInterval2, pandaHprInterval2, name="pandaPace")
        self.pandaPace.loop( ) 

    def spinCameraTask( self, task ):
        angleDegrees = task.time * 6.0
        angleRadians = angleDegrees * ( pi / 180.0 )
        self.camera.setPos( 20 * sin( angleRadians ), -20.0 * cos( angleRadians ), 3 )
        self.camera.setHpr( angleDegrees, 0, 0 )
        return Task.cont

app = MyApp( )
app.run( )
```

Comment: @Montreal, а что тут можно сказать? Я правильно понимаю, что это схема клиента (иначе при чем тут 3D Render)?

Или я не прав?

--

Правда, на этом браузере я схему не вижу, но видел ее вчера на другом. Слишком она общая. Все связаны через ядро друг с другом. На самом же деле вряд ли Render как-то взаимодействует с Save/Load. 

А что делает Input? Водит изменения по сети от сервера?

Вы бы как-то поподробней расписали сначала клиент-серверную архитектуру и распределение функций (и обмен данными) между клиентами (кстати, есть локальный storage?) и сервером.

Comment: Как-то не думал, что у меня клиент-серверная архитектура вырисовывается. Вообще я стараюсь сделать так, чтобы все составные части друг от друга как можно меньше зависели. 

В **ядре** вся игровая логика.

**3D render** отрисовывает трёхмерную графику.

**Input** считывает то, что пользователь вводит с клавиатуры/мыши.

**GUI** - графический интерфейс пользователя. Nuff said.

Названия остальных модулей, вроде, говорят сами за себя. Вообще пример я брал с шахматных программ, где к одному графическому интерфейсу есть куча движков, и наоборот, которые общаются по стандартизированному протоколу.

Comment: @Montreal, наверное я правда не понял исходной посылки.

Вы говорите об однопользовательской графической программе для локального компьютера (никаких сетей, браузеров и т.п.)?

Кстати, тогда уж уточните -- это винда?

Comment: @avp, вроде бы в исходном описании клиент-серверы и не значились.

Comment: @Nofate, похоже, что так. Наверное меня сбила фраза

    За основу я взял персонажа из Diablo II 

в описании идеи. Насколько я помню, молодежь у нас в фирме, кода-то резалась в нее по сети.

Comment: @avp да, я говорю об однопользовательской игре, хотя такая структура и не мешает сделать её многопользовательской. На удалённый сервер можно отправлять только время прохождения, а весь игровой процесс должен проходить на локальной машине.

в **Diablo II** и синглплеер, и мультиплеер были на хорошем уровне)

Comment: @Montreal по идее вам бы тогда продумать интерфейсы взаимодействия модулей, чтобы абстрагироваться от реализации.

Comment: @smackmychi, на 100% абстрагироваться от реализации всё равно не получится, так как используемые библиотеки имеют свой API и это накладывает свой отпечаток. Ну а без сторонних библиотек сейчас ни в одном проекте не обходится.

Comment: @Montreal 100% это не необходимое условие. Такой уровень абстракции может оказаться избыточным в плане затрат на реализацию. А вот сделать удобно, думаю, вполне возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Ну ёлки, а сама идея где, ведь если как вы правильно заметили: "идея ничего не стоит без реализации", то страха опубликовать быть не должно.

А в остальном:

1. Плюсы - плохо, потому что тяжело.
2. Нужно быстро прототип написать (рекомендую Grails, ну для python'а есть что-то похожее Django), если идея будет стоящая её потом сто раз перепишут.
3. Ваша цель прототип (должен основную фишку показывать), такой чтобы было понятно для чего это нужно и кому

В первую очередь те этапы которые позволят проекту запускаться, работать и предоставлять ту функциональность ради которой писали, а потом украшать и удобство. Причём удобным в первую очередь должен быть процесс позволяющий отразить замысел.

Comment: Идея по первой ссылке. Там многабукав, поэтому я не стал всё сюда копировать. 

Если это будет крайне необходимо, то я постараюсь ужать описание в 2000+ слов до 200, хотя не уверен, что это хорошо получится, так как при развёрнутом описании идеи я старался быть максимально кратким.

Также, если это необходимо, могу текст на который дана ссылка, выложить здесь.

Comment: @avp, где-то тут мы с вами обсуждали право на существование мечей в мире далёкого будущего, и вот только сейчас мне в голову пришла такая мысль: они вполне хороши как оружие при наличии телепортации. Портируемся вплотную к противнику, отсекаем всё лишнее, телепортируемся обратно.
???
PROFIT.
Также я уже упоминал про существование брони, которую не пробивают пули, про то, что стрелковое оружие может заедать, оно тяжелее и пр...
Видимо, зря вы мечи похоронили)

Comment: @Montreal, да уж. 

При наличии телепортации и гвоздь сгодится. Телепортируем ЕГО внутрь противника -- PROFIT!!!

Comment: @avp, противник может быть в доспехах, которые препятствуют телепортированию инородных предметов внутрь него. Правда, тогда могут существовать и помещения, где телепортация не работает и наши любители холодного оружия попадут в весьма затруднительное положение.

Оружие, которое телепортирует гвозди в голову противника можно сделать игровым супер-оружием, которое позволяет убить любого монстра с одного выстрела.

Comment: @Montreal сарказм же был, чего вы так все серьезно воспринимаете?

Comment: @smackmychi, да мне просто реально мысль о подобном оружии самому приходила.
Ну и по буквам сложно распознать интонацию собеседника :)

Comment: @Montreal тогда помните о балансе сил и лучше сразу определиться, что понимается под термином телепортации.

Comment: Подпишусь на бложик, тем более в соседней области нахожусь, может выйти что-нибудь интересное.